# How to find an integer solution for general Diophantine equation $ax + by + cz + dt... = N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I know how to solve $ax + by = c$ using Extended Algorithm. But with more than variables, I'm lost :(.

To verify if it has an integer solution is easy, since we only need to check for $\gcd(a,b,c)|d$. Other than that, how can we find an integer solution for this equation?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Use the extended Euclidean algorithm several more times.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: for each pair (a,b) then ((a,b), c)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose you need to solve 
$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 = c\qquad (1)$$
in integers.

I claim this is equivalent to solving 
$$\gcd(a_1,a_2)y + a_3x_3 = c\qquad (2)$$
in integers.

To see this, note that any solution to (1) produces a solution to (2): letting $g=\gcd(a_1,a_2)$, we can write $a_1 = gk_1$, $a_2=gk_2$, so then we have:
$$c = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 = g(k_1x_1) + g(k_2x_2) + a_3x_3 = g(k_1x_1+k_2x_2) + a_3x_3,$$
solving (2). Conversely, suppose you have a solution to (2). Since we can find $r$ and $s$ such that $g=ra_1+sa_2$, we have
$$c = gy+a_3x_3 = (ra_1+sa_2)y +a_3x_3 = a_1(ry) + a_2(sy) + a_3x_3,$$
yielding a solution to (1).

This should tell you how to solve the general case
$$a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n = c$$
in terms of $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, which can in turn be computed recursively.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3327153/242) for a proof and worked examples for the case of three variables (the method generalizes to any number of variables, as above).