# Fastest way to find the integer solution of a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have the following equation $$\frac{ax+by}{t}= \text{an integer}$$ and $a$, $b$ and $t$ are known. I also have a set of solutions for $x$ and $y$ out of which only one will satisfy the above equation. Without having to resort to trying each solution out, which is the fastest way (if it exists) to figure out the correct values of $x$ and $y$? Does something like a Chinese remainder theorem help here? And how to proceed if $a$ and $b$ are co-prime?

Comment: See:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/how-to-find-an-integer-solution-for-general-diophantine-equation-ax-by-cz?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but that does not help much. What if $a$ and $b$ are co-prime? Then their gcd is 1 and I back to square one.

Comment: are $a,b,t$ real , integers?

Comment: Yes, indeed they are integers and real!

Comment: What is known about gcd(a,t) ? gcd(b,t) ?

Comment: gcd(a,t) and  gcd(b,t) both are co-prime.